# Update textInput value in shiny without triggering event that is being observed for

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a `shiny` app that lets the user select and highlight points on a timeseries. One feature lets the user dynamically change the averaging bin of the underlying timeseries. To avoid erroneous highlights, I want the user to be able to decide if they want to proceed changing the bin size after highlights have already been made, with "yes" deleting all existing highlights, and "cancel" retaining the previous status and not changing the bin size.

My problem is reverting the displayed value in the input field to the previous value after "cancel" has been selected, as `updateTextInput` triggers the dialog box a second time (because highlights already exist). I feel like this should be an easy solution, but I keep drawing blank.

In addition, even if I hit "cancel", existing highlights disappear on the plot.

```
df <- data.frame(t=seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00", tz='UTC'),
                        as.POSIXct("2024-01-02 00:00:00", tz='UTC'), by="1 hour"),
                 V1=sample(1:50,25, replace=T))
```

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textInput("bin", HTML("Average by x hours"), 
              value = "1", width ='175px', placeholder = NULL),
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

modal_confirm <- modalDialog(
  "This will remove all highlights. Are you sure you want to continue?",
  title = "",
  footer = tagList(
    actionButton("cancel", "Cancel"),
    actionButton("ok", "Continue")
  )
)
```

```
server<- function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals<-reactiveValues(
    highlights = data.frame(),
    prev_bin = NULL,
  )
    
  #some data manipulation
  dat<-reactive({
    return(as.data.frame(df%>%
                           group_by(t=round_date(t, unit=paste0(vals$prev_bin,' hours')))%>%
                           summarize(V1=median(V1))))
  })
  
  #draw the plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    dat() %>%
      plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(x= ~t, y = ~V1, type='scatter', mode='line', visible=TRUE) %>%
      layout(showlegend=FALSE)
  })
  
  #make highlights
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"),{
    
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    vals$highlights<-rbind(vals$highlights,dat()[d$pointNumber+1,]) 
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "addTraces", 
        list(
          x = list(d$x), y = list(d$y), type = 'scatter',
          marker = list(symbol='x', size=10, color='red')))
  })
  
  #trying to change the averaging bin after higlights have already been made? Ask!
  observeEvent(input$bin,{
    if(nrow(vals$highlights) > 0 ){
      vals$prev_bin <- c(dplyr::last(vals$prev_bin), input$bin)
      showModal(modal_confirm)
    }else{
      vals$prev_bin<-input$bin
    }
  })
  
  #if ok, change averaging bin, all previous highlights will be deleted
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    vals$prev_bin <- dplyr::last(vals$prev_bin)
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "deleteTraces", seq_len(nrow(vals$highlights)))
    
    vals$highlights <- data.frame()

    removeModal()
  })
  
  #if cancel, 
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    vals$prev_bin<-vals$prev_bin[1]
    removeModal()
    updateTextInput(session, "bin",
                    value = vals$prev_bin)
  })
  
  #data table of highlights
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
      vals$highlights
  })  
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Does `observeEvent(input$cancel, { isolate({  <your existing code> }) })` help?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Comment: @Limey I could have misunderstood but I don't think this is the problem. The problem is that the `updateTextInput` triggers the observer that opens the modal.

Comment: @Stéphane, correct. I want to avoid the ```updateTextInput``` triggering the observer/modal a second time. I'm also somehow losing my highlights just in the plot even if selecting cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem with the triggering, I use a TRUE/FALSE value `React` which blocks the reactivity if it is `FALSE`

To solve the disappearing of the points, I use `plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", ...` to update the data.

```r
df <- data.frame(t=seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00", tz='UTC'),
                       as.POSIXct("2024-01-02 00:00:00", tz='UTC'), by="1 hour"),
                 V1=sample(1:50,25, replace=T))
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

makeData <- function(bin) {
  as.data.frame(
    df %>%
      group_by(t = round_date(t, unit=paste0(bin,' hours')))%>%
      summarize(V1 = median(V1))
  )
}

updatePlot <- function(session, dat) {
  plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke(
      "restyle", 
      list(
        x = list(dat$t), y = list(dat$V1)
      ), 0
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textInput("bin", HTML("Average by x hours"), 
              value = "1", width ='175px', placeholder = NULL),
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

modal_confirm <- modalDialog(
  "This will remove all highlights. Are you sure you want to continue?",
  title = "",
  footer = tagList(
    actionButton("cancel", "Cancel"),
    actionButton("ok", "Continue")
  )
)

server<- function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals<-reactiveValues(
    highlights = data.frame(),
    prev_bin = NULL,
  )
  
  Dat <- eventReactive(input$bin, {
    makeData(input$bin)
  })
  
  #draw the plot
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    isolate(Dat()) %>%
      plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(x= ~t, y = ~V1, type='scatter', mode='line', visible=TRUE) %>%
      layout(showlegend=FALSE)
  })
  
  #make highlights
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"),{
    
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    vals$highlights <- rbind(vals$highlights,Dat()[d$pointNumber+1,]) 
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "addTraces", 
        list(
          x = list(d$x), y = list(d$y), type = 'scatter',
          marker = list(symbol='x', size=10, color='red')))
  })
  
  React <- TRUE
  
  observeEvent(input$bin, {
    if(React) {
      if(nrow(vals$highlights) > 0 ){
        vals$prev_bin <- c(dplyr::last(vals$prev_bin), input$bin)
        showModal(modal_confirm)
      }else{
        vals$prev_bin <- input$bin
        updatePlot(session, makeData(input$bin))
      }
    }
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(input$bin, {
    message("reset React")
    React <<- TRUE
  }, priority = 1)
  
  #if ok, change averaging bin, all previous highlights will be deleted
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    vals$prev_bin <- dplyr::last(vals$prev_bin)
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        "deleteTraces", seq_len(nrow(vals$highlights)))
    
    vals$highlights <- data.frame()
    
    updatePlot(session, makeData(vals$prev_bin))
    
    removeModal()
  })
  
  #if cancel, 
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    React <<- FALSE
    vals$prev_bin <- vals$prev_bin[1]
    removeModal()
    updateTextInput(session, "bin",
                    value = vals$prev_bin)
  })
  
  #data table of highlights
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
    vals$highlights
  })  
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I actually came up with a similar approach for avoiding the triggering, but yours is much cleaner. Good to know I can set different priorities, too, I didn't know that. Can I ask what the purpose of the isolate in ```isolate(Dat()) %>% plot_ly ...``` is?

Comment: @Anke I isolate in order that this plot does not react to a change of `Dat()`. This was the reason for which you lost the marked points.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Also, is there a reason you're calling ```makeData()``` again in the ```updatePlot()``` call instead of using ```Dat()```?

Comment: @Anke Because both `Dat` and the plot update react to `input$bin`, so I wasn't sure that `Dat` was updated in time. We could use `priority` instead of doing that.

Comment: I would be interested to see how to solve this with ```priority```. I have a more complex version that also allows changes to the starttime of the timeseries as well as subsetting of the data, and I'd like to pass a different reactive that depends on ```Dat``` to ```updatePlot```. I also don't know what I exactly I changed, but ```isolate``` appears to no longer work after adding this additional complexity and the plot is already updated before a selection in the modal is made

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of my problem to avoid `updateTextInput` triggering the observer/modal by adding a reactive that keeps track of whether or not "cancelled" was selected.

```
  vals<-reactiveValues(
    highlights = data.frame(),
    prev_bin = NULL,
    cancelled=F
  )
```

and then

```
  observeEvent(input$bin,{
    if(nrow(vals$highlights) > 0 ){
      vals$prev_bin <- c(dplyr::last(vals$prev_bin), input$bin)
      if(!vals$cancelled){
      showModal(modal_confirm)
        }else{ vals$cancelled=F}
    }else{
      vals$prev_bin<-input$bin
    }
  })
```

and

```
  #if cancel, 
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    vals$cancelled=T
    vals$prev_bin<-vals$prev_bin[1]
    removeModal()
    updateTextInput(session, "bin",
                    value = vals$prev_bin)
  })
```

However, I'm still facing the problem that my additional traces (highlights) disappear upon trigger of the modal. Trace 0 is not updated until after an answer was made in the modal, but the highlights disappear immediately. They're not deleted, just hidden(?). If I add more functionality to my app that lets the user change the layout, they will reappear in a subsequent step.